# some confusion about `tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad`

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I`m moving a project from r0.11 to r0.10, and I have some bug in 0.10 running this script:

```
  print('before', label.get_shape())
  label = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(label, h, w)
  print('after',label.get_shape())
```

the results is :

```
 ('before', TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None), Dimension(1)]))  
 ('after', TensorShape([Dimension(321), Dimension(321), Dimension(None)]))
```

but when I test in r0,11, the results:

```
 ('before', TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None), Dimension(1)]))
 ('after', TensorShape([Dimension(321), Dimension(321), Dimension(1)]))
```

the input of the above two functions is the same.
I can not find where it gets wrong.

Comment: Going to an older version of tensorflow is more likely to introduce older bugs.

Comment: I would stick with newer TF version. Note that 0.11 produces the more precise answer.